Why does learning theory study generalization bounds?
Disclaimer: I know that mathematics needs no external motivation to be developed, and that such view is (in the long term) helpful even for applications. Nonetheless, I believe it is crucial for applied mathematicians to reflect on such questions from time to time, hence this post.
--
So far, the only reasonable answer I have been able to come up with is that such bounds have led to advances in algorithm design. The main example I know is how the early margin-related bounds of M. Aizerman, E. Braverman, L. Rozonoer influenced Vapnik to develop max-margin methods, in particular SVMs.
However, I think this view is only partially true for boosting and mostly false for NNs (here, learning theory tries to understand their generalization ability post hoc their success). This makes me curious about the practical applicability of these bounds.
--
Having said that, I would like to attract complimentary comments on different facets of the exploration of generalization bounds and their practical usefulness.

I think this question would get better answers on https://ai.stackexchange.com/ or https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Are you interested in what was the historical motivation for considering these bounds, or in whether they are useful practically? These are two separate questions.

@SimonSegert The main focus of the question is on practical usefulness
